# How to extend the Serializable interface to all sub Class?

Tags: java

I have the Base class as

```
public class SuperDto  implements Serializable{

public SupeDto() {
}   
@Getter
@Setter
int statusCode;
```

}

Whether all my subclass take the advantage of interface Serializable by default or i need to implement manually  in all my sub class

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html:  "All subtypes of a serializable class are themselves serializable".   :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All subclasses of a serializable class will be serializable by default So no need to implement serializable explicitly. If you don't want the subclass to be serializable, you need to implement writeObject() and readObject() and throw NotSerializableException.

Answer (score 0):

Any class extending SuperDto will automatically be a subtype of Serializable too. So you won't need to type 'implements Serializable' again.